# ASP.NET: Localization: Get .resx value in MVC view using dynamic key

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have a view, and in this view, I need to get a value from an App_GlobalResources file using a dynamic key.

Normally, for example, I would do this:

```
<%= Resources.IndexView.MyKey %>
```

However, in this case, I need to do something like:

```
<%= Resources.IndexView[keyRoot + Model.BlahBlah] %>
```

I don't want to get into a discussion about separation of concerns and all that. I just want to know how to use Resources (ResourceManager)? to write out a .resx value using a dynamic key for an entry in a App_GlobalResources file.

Answer (score 4):

you could use GetGlobalResourceObject

so something like

```
(String)GetGlobalResourceObject(
            "IndexView", keyRoot + Model.BlahBlah)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, how to Get a string from the Global Resources, Thx!